# How do I click depending on state of toggle switch?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a toggle switch I want to click depending on what the switch state is.

If it is "span.switch-right" I want to do:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("span.switch-left")).click();
```

If it is "span.switch-left" I want to do:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("span.switch-right")).click();
```

HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="has-switch switch-on switch-animate">
    <div>
        <span class="switch-left">ON</span>
        <label for="profile_isProfileSharedWithNearby">&nbsp;</label>
        <span class="switch-right">OFF</span>
        <input id="profile_isProfileSharedWithNearby" name="profile[isProfileSharedWithNearby]" class="form-control-borderless hide" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML in two different switch states?

Comment: <div tabindex="0" class="has-switch switch-on switch-animate"><div><span class="switch-left">ON</span><label for="profile_isProfileSharedWithNearby">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">OFF</span><input id="profile_isProfileSharedWithNearby" name="profile[isProfileSharedWithNearby]" class="form-control-borderless hide" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></div></div>

Comment: Please edit the question and include it. Thanks.

Comment: I have done that. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to give `Fluent Wait` a try. It gives you the ability to wait for an element bypassing some exception types and poll `DOM` after a certain period of time and make sure if that exists or not.

```
By by = By.cssSelector("span.switch-left");
// Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
// for its presence once every 5 seconds.
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
});

foo.click();
```

Taken from [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

**Edit**
Provided solution after confusing(;-)) discussion

```
//*[@tabindex='0'][contains(@class,'switch-off')]
```

Comment: I am using a modified fluent wait method but don't want to use it for conditional clauses as it adds considerable delays.

Comment: What do you mean by **considerable delays**? Don't you have to wait for the element state change anyway? In fact it's not hard coded delay. It will go forward as soon as it finds the element.

Comment: I think I might not have explained myself correctly. Please have a look at my response to Richard.

Comment: @ratsstack I have. Looking at the `html` you provide `<span class="switch-left">ON</span>
        <label for="profile_isProfileSharedWithNearby">&nbsp;</label>
        <span class="switch-right">OFF</span>` I am confused as @richard said as well. I see the `ON` and `OFF` both are on the `html`. Then how do you determine which one you want to click on?

Comment: No, in the HTML I've provided switch-left is ON and switch-right is OFF. They are referring to the same switch!

Comment: OK, so in that case you cannot refer the `Selenium` two different elements at the same time. Then what you do? I see `left` is ON and right is OFF. Do you want to click right one then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71628/discussion-between-saifur-and-ratsstack).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the text is reliable, you could use an xpath selector for this:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'switch-') and contains(text(), 'OFF')]")).click();
```

This will always click the `OFF` switch.

Comment: Will this not fail if the text is "ON"? I need a condition to check if the switch is either ON or OFF.

Comment: @ratsstack I'm not entirely clear on what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is change the state of the switch from ON to OFF (if it is ON) and OFF to ON (if it is OFF). To be able to do this I need to check the state of the switch first i.e. whether it is ON or OFF.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the switch state by following code and can switch it off its on

```
List<WebElement> switchElement = driver.findElements(By
            .cssSelector("div.has-switch.switch-on.switch-animate"));
    System.out.println(switchElement.size() + " : Switch Size");
    // Check its on, if its on then switch it off
    if (switchElement.size() != 0) {

        switchElement.get(0)
                .findElement(By.cssSelector("span.switch-left")).click();

    } else
        System.out.println("Switch  is already off");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up doing something similar once the Richard and Saifur helped me figure out the HTML.